# Foundation Flexible Div Height in Nested Rows when using Equalizer

Tags: javascript, css, zurb-foundation

I'm using foundation (5) to layout my grid. Foundation uses equalizer to enable you to measure columns against each other. I'm using this to good effect but it only gets me so far...

When I nest my rows I get a gap - really I need a flexible height on the quote box that fills the gap(see image). I have tried using JS to match the height of the container's equalized value but it just grows the box continually when the window is resized.

Does anyone have any advice on how to expand a div's height in a fluid responsive way so that it's (absolute positioned) content grows with it?

[image]

```
<!-- START Tier One -->
<div class="row" data-equalizer="foo" data-equalizer-mq="large-up">

  <div class="large-4 large-push-8 medium-12 medium-push-12 small-12 columns" data-equalizer-watch="foo">
    <div class="row" data-equalizer="tierOne" data-equalizer-mq="medium-only">
      <div class="large-12 medium-6 small-12 columns">
        <!-- Video -->
      </div>
      <div class="large-12 medium-6 small-12 columns case-study-col">

        <div class="card show-for-medium-up case-study-parent" data-equalizer-watch="tierOne">
          <a href="/case-studies/">
            <div class="card__case-study case-study-child">
              <div class="card__case-study-img" style="background-image:url('img/image.jpg');">
              </div>
              <div class="card__case-study-content">
                <blockquote class="">
                  "<perch:content id="quote_featured" type="textarea" />"
                  <cite>
                          <perch:if exists="quote_avatar_featured">
                            <img src="img/avatar.jpg">
                          </perch:if>
                          <div class="q-cite">
                          </div>
                  </cite>
                </blockquote>

              </div>
              <div class="card__case-study-bg">
              </div>
            </div>
          </a>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="large-8 large-pull-4 medium-12 medium-pull-12 small-12 columns" data-equalizer-watch="foo">



    <div class="card">
      <div class="row collapse">

        <div class="large-12 medium-6 small-12 columns">
          <div class="row collapse">
            <div class="large-5 medium-12 small-12 columns">
              <!-- news image -->
            </div>
            <div class="large-7 medium-12 small-12 columns">
              <!-- news text -->
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>



  </div>

</div>
<!-- END Teir One -->
```

Comment: Is this only when you're using an image in the box, or for all boxes?

Comment: Please post some code so we can fix your issue. Hard to do it with a screenshot.

Comment: Code now added to the post